# is there a way to listen to events using JavaScript, Jquery in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list of names which is fetched from database, I want when user select any one of the name then its id will be saved in a variable & then on submit the form I receive this id on server. I am wondering is it possible? I am pretty new to this technology.

Here's my code

controller

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            MyUsers user = new MyUsers();
            List<MyUsers> result = user.GetAllUser();
            return View(result);
        }
```

View

```
<h2>Products</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@item.Name</li>
}
</ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Click Me" />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// To save the list content/id

var listcontent = '';
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
   listcontent = $(this).text(); // if you want id of list then : listcontent = this.id;
});

// Send the list data to server

$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function() {
   // assumed that you're sending GET reqeust
   $.get('url_to_script?val=' + listcontent, function(res) {
     // res contains data returned from server
   })
});
```

Comment: i want to send it to server when my asp.net button is clicked, & if user selects the other name then can listcontent be change?

Comment: @JeloMelo during each click on list the `listcontent` will change

Comment: thanx, one more question, can i achieve the same thing when user on swipeleft, on swiperight event of jquery mobile?

Comment: @JeloMelo Yup possible. you are welcome, best way to thank any one who's answer you choose is accepting that answer. Thanks

Comment: then what do i need to write? $('ul li').on('swipeleft', function() {
   listcontent = $(this).text(); ???
});

Comment: @JeloMelo you can use also $("ul li").swipeleft(function() {
    listcontent = $(this).text();
});